# cant run test node.js http script : connection not found

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu

In Kubuntu I have installed node.js `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Then I made a js file called example.js containing

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Then I ran the file with `node example.js`

but I do not see the log

In the browser I get a error saying connection not found.

if I `ping http://127.0.0.1`  then I get a error saying unknown host

what am I doing wrong? have I installed node.js incorrectly?

Comment: Ubuntu and its flavors already have a `node`, [so Node.js goes by another name](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os) on these systems: "*There is a naming conflict with the node package (Amateur Packet Radio Node Program), and the nodejs binary has been renamed from `node` to `nodejs`.*"

Comment: change this to an answer and Ill mark it. it worked you where correct thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ubuntu and its flavors [already have a `node`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/node), Node.js [goes by another name](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os) on these systems:

> There is a naming conflict with the node package (Amateur Packet Radio Node Program), and the nodejs binary has been renamed from `node` to `nodejs`.

So, at least on that machine, you'll have to instead use:

```
nodejs example.js
```

---

Also, you might use [`cURL`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) instead to test as `ping` isn't an HTTP client.

```sh
curl http://127.0.0.1:1337/
```

And, as others have already noted, you'll have to include the specified port (`.listen(1337,`) in the URL since it's non-default.